# syslog-ng adds <14> to handler name in log file

Tags: django, syslog-ng

After I upgraded syslog-ng from version 3.0 to 3.1 I somehow get <14> and sometimes
<12> before the handler name in my syslog files for my django website, like this:

```
Nov  2 17:11:15 servername <14>handler.log [INFO]: Some logging ...
```

Does anyone know how to get rid of the <14> logging?

Comment: The number in <> is the [priority value][1] of the message.


  [1]: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3164#section-4.1.1